Datomic and Paramaterized :where clauses
I have this:
(defn entities [entity-map]
  (db/q
    '[:find [(pull ?e pattern) ...]
      :in $ pattern ?primary-field
      :where [?e ?primary-field]]
    (:pattern entity-map)
    (:primary entity-map)))

which works great.  but now I want something like this:
(defn entities-where [entity-map & where-clauses]
  (db/q '[:find [(pull ?e pattern) ...]
         :in $ pattern ?primary-field [?where ...]
         :where
         [?e ?primary-field]
         ?where]
    (:pattern entity-map)
    (:primary entity-map)
    where-clauses))

But can't seem to make it work.
example entity maps are:
{:primary :lead/id
   :pattern '[*, {:lead/status [*]}]}

another approach was:
(defn entities-where [entity-map where-clause]
  (db/q '[:find [(pull ?e pattern) ...]
         :in $ pattern ?primary-field where+
         :where
          [?e ?primary-field]
          where+]
    (:pattern entity-map)
    (:primary entity-map)
    where-clause))

(entities-where my-entity-map '[?e :touch/time 1720546420839])

but still no dice: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol

Have you tried conj-ing the variable part to the query?

You cannot pass where clauses as arguments to a query. You need to programmatically build your query. It would like this
(defn entities-where [entity-map & where-clauses]
  (db/q (into
          '[:find [(pull ?e pattern) ...]
           :in $ pattern ?primary-field [?where ...]
           :where
           [?e ?primary-field]]
          where-clauses)
    (:pattern entity-map)
    (:primary entity-map)))

I would suggest using the map form which is easier to construct programmatically.
This would look like this :
(defn entities-where [entity-map & where-clauses]
  (db/q 
    (assoc
      '{:find ...
       :in ...}
      :where
      (into '[[?e ?primary-field]]
            where-clauses))
    (:pattern entity-map)
    (:primary entity-map)))

Although similar, the latter is more maintainable as it does not assume the order of the clauses (keywords) in the query (which means you an assoc and get easily using this form).
